# How do I loop through two files and combine the same?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I do have two text files and want to loop through both files then combine both line (line 1 of first test file and line1 of second text file. like that for thousands of lines) and do some function

I am familiar with loop through one file and for that code is given below:

```
$lines = file('data.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {

//some function


}
```

but how will I do for two files and combine bothe lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "search table"?  What do you want to search for?

Comment: say some data from two files combine together by line by line then search table1 and store result to table2.

Comment: @limo: Yes, but search for *what*?  Please add an example of your file structure and table layouts to the question.

Comment: Need clarification here. What are the contents of table1? What do you want to search for in table1? And what do you want to store in table2?

Comment: I do have two text file one is names and another is with details. I want ti seperate it in these formats. my questions is how do I loop through both files and combine each lines. forget about tables as of now.

Comment: Do both files have the same number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by search through the table, but to open both files and do stuff with them:

```
$file1 = fopen("/path/to/file1.txt","r"); //Open file with read only access
$file2 = fopen("/path/to/file2.txt","r");
$combined = fopen("/path/to/combined.txt","w"); //in case you want to write the combined lines to a new file

while(!feof($file1) && !feof($file2))
{
     $line1 = trim(fgets($file1));  //Grab a line of the first file, note the trim will clip off the carriage return/new line at the end of the line, can remove it if you don't need it.
     $line2 = trim(fgets($file2));  //Grab a line of the second file

     $combline = $line1 . $line2;

     fwrite($combined,$combline . "\r\n"); //Write to new combined file, and add a new carriage return/newline at the end of the combined line to replace the one trimmed off.

     //You can do whatever with data from $line1, $line2, or the combined $combline after getting them.
}
```

Note:  You might run into trouble if you hit the end of file on one file before the other, which would only happen if they aren't the same length, might need some if control statements to set $line1 or $line2 to `""` or something else if `feof()` their respective files, once both hit the end of file, the while loop will end.

Comment: This is the best example so far. And kudos for remembering to use `fgets`, most PHP users seem to forget it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically as Crayon and Tim have shown. If both files have the same number of lines, it should work. If the line number is different you will have to loop over the larger file to make sure you get all lines or check EOF on both.

To combine line by line, I often use the unix command paste which is very fast. This also accounts for files with different lengths. Run this on the command line:

```
paste file1 file2 > output.txt
```

See the `manpage` for `paste` for command line options, field delimiters.

```
man paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$file1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rb");
$file2 = fopen("file2.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file1)) {
  $combined = fread($file1, 8192) . " " . fread($file2, 8192);
  // now insert $combined into db
}
fclose($file1);
fclose($file2);
```

- you will want to use the longer of the two files in the while condition.
- you may need to adjust the bytes read in fread depending on how long your lines are
- change " " to whatever delimiter you want